# Link template to edit previously submitted form by a User in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I made a web app where the user can submit a form. I want the user to be able to view his submission but I can't figure out how to access the previously submitted data.

I keep getting an error related to failing to reverse match failure.
The error says
**Reverse for 'submission' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['submission/(?P<application_id>[0-9]+)/$']**

Views.py

```
@login_required
def apply(request):
    """Submit application"""
    if request.method != 'POST':
        form = ApplicationForm()
    else:
        form = ApplicationForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_application = form.save(commit=False)
            new_application.owner = request.user
            new_application.save()
            return redirect('credit_apply:submitted')
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'credit_apply/apply.html', context)

def submission(request, application_id):
    """View and maybe? edit application"""
    application = Application.objects.get(id=application_id)
    owner = application.owner

    if request.method != 'POST':
        form = ApplicationForm(instance=application)
    else:
        form = ApplicationForm(instance=application, data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('credit_apply:submitted', owner_id=owner.id)
    context = {'application': application, 'owner': owner, 'form': form}
    return render(request, 'credit_apply/submission.html', context)
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from phonenumber_field.modelfields import PhoneNumberField
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model as user_model

User = user_model()
# Create your models here.

class Application(models.Model):
    """App para las aplicacions de credito"""
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    business = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    m_number = PhoneNumberField(max_length=16)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, unique=True)

    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.first_name} {self.last_name} {self.business}"
```

url pattern

```
path('submission/<int:application_id>/', views.submission, name='submission')
```

base template line that is causing the error to pop up

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'credit_apply:submission' application.id%}">
    Edita!</a></li>
....
```

Comment: The `apply_view` is lacking the `apply_id` in your `{% url ... %}`.

Comment: Do you mean adding it to the tag like so `<a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'credit_apply:apply_view' apply_id %}">Edita!</a></li>` ? I've tried that before but it doesn't fix the issue

Comment: no, since you did not pass any value for that to the template.

Comment: I updated my post and made some naming changes to make it easier to read. I passed a new argument in the redirect function in the view but I still get the same error. I am new at this and trying to teach myself, I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

changed my view to:

```
def submission(request):
    """View and maybe? edit application"""
    model = Application
    application = Application.objects.get(owner=request.user)

    if request.method != 'POST':
        form = ApplicationForm(instance=application)
    else:
        form = ApplicationForm(instance=application, data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('credit_apply:submitted')
    context = {'application': application, 'form': form}
    return render(request, 'credit_apply/submission.html', context)
```

removed the application_id pattern and application.id tag in template since no longer needed